# Case when loop in MySQL returns the wrong value

Tags: mysql

To finalize my MySQL questions for today I'd like to get some suggestions on this matter. I have a table to which I need to add a column with a calculated value. I'm not looking to update the table - just combine information.
The table I'm working with is looking like this:

```
        +----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
        | VOTE_CANDIDATE | ORIGINAL_VOTES | SURPLUS_REDISTRIBUTION_TO_CANDIDATES |
        +----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
        |              1 |              8 |                                   -1 |
        |              2 |              1 |                                   -1 |
        |              3 |              2 |                                   -1 |
        |              4 |              4 |                                   -1 |
        |              5 |              2 |                                   -1 |
        |              6 |              3 |                                   -1 |
        +----------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

My problem is that only row 1 should return -1 on column SURPLUS_REDISTRIBUTION_TO_CANDIDATES since it's ORIGINAL_VOTES is greater than the threshold of 7. The rest should (as the case when below states) return zero since it's below the threshold. It seems as the query locks on the first row and then reuses SURPLUS_REDISTRIBUTION_TO_CANDIDATES on all rows. This is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT vote_candidate, COUNT(*) original_votes, CASE
  WHEN (
    (
      SELECT MAX(
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
          FROM vote_orders
        )
      ) votes
      FROM vote_orders
      WHERE vote_order = 1
    ) >= (
      SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
      FROM votes
    )
  )
  THEN (
    SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
    FROM votes
  ) - (
    SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold) votes
    FROM (
      SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
      FROM vote_orders
      WHERE vote_order = 1
      GROUP BY vote_candidate
      HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
        SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
        FROM votes
      )
    ) t
    WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
      SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
      FROM vote_orders
    )
  )
  ELSE 0
END surplus_redistribution_to_candidates
FROM vote_orders
WHERE vote_order = 1
GROUP BY vote_candidate;
```

How do I achieve the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having difficulty deciphering what your query does, and why it's doing what it does.

It looks like there's a single "threshold"; that's calculated as an expression from a query against the `votes` table.

If the goal is to return a non-positive difference between the "threshold" value and the "orginal_votes" value for each candidate, I would do it like this:

```
SELECT c.vote_candidate
     , c.original_votes
     , LEAST(0,t.threshold - c.original_votes) AS surplus_redistribution_to_candidates
  FROM ( SELECT o.vote_candidate
              , COUNT(*) original_votes
           FROM vote_orders o
          WHERE o.vote_order = 1
          GROUP
             BY o.vote_candidate
       ) c
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) AS threshold
           FROM votes
        ) t
 ORDER BY c.vote_candidate
```

The inline view aliased as c gets the "original_votes" for each candidate, and the inline view aliased as "t" gets the "threshold". The outer query compares the two values, and returns either the difference (if it is negative) or zero.

---

I don't think your query is locking onto the first row. Rather, I think the issue is that every execution of those `SELECT MAX()` subqueries returns the same values for every `vote_candidate`. And its just coincidence that the maximum value happens to be associated with the "first" `vote_candidate` in the resultset.

It looks like you just want to compare the "original_votes" for each vote_candidate to the "threshold" value. It looks as if all those subqueries are entirely unnecessary; they are just causing confusion.

---

If you want to avoid using the MySQL `LEAST()` function, and use an ANSI standard `CASE` expression, then you could

replace this:

```
    LEAST(0,t.threshold - c.original_votes)
```

with this:

```
    CASE
    WHEN t.threshold < c.original_votes
    THEN t.threshold - c.original_votes
    ELSE 0
    END
```

Comment: Great answer. Not only does it work - you also clarified things for me. I must admit - the entire query to which this snippet belongs is even more confusing. This solution though sheds some light on it. :) thank you very much! Up voted and marked as an answer.

Comment: If the entire query is as confusing as this snippet, you might want to rethink the approach of the entire query, especially if your query includes subqueries, and especially if it repeats the same subquery multiple times. I suspect that there is a much simpler (and easier to understand) approach to solving the problem.